# Ant include external .jar

Tags: java, ant, jar, build.xml

I want to include external jar to my java project. I'm using ant. External .jar is in folder lib. My build.xml looks something like that:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project>
    <path id="classpath">
        <fileset dir="lib" includes="**/*.jar"/>
    </path>

    <target name="clean">
        <delete dir="build"/>
    </target>

    <target name="compile">
        <mkdir dir="build"/>
        <javac srcdir="src" destdir="build" classpathref="classpath" />
    </target>

    <target name="jar">
        <mkdir dir="trash"/>
        <jar destfile="trash/test.jar" basedir="build">
            <zipgroupfileset dir="lib" includes="**/*.jar"/>
            <manifest>
                <attribute name="Main-Class" value="com.Test"/>
            </manifest>
        </jar>
    </target>

    <target name="run">
        <java jar="trash/test.jar" fork="true"/>
    </target>
</project>
```

But it doesn't work. When I want to import something from the external .jar, there is an error after command `ant compile`: package com.something does not exist.. What should I edit to get it working?

Exact error:

```
  Compiling 23 source files to xy/build
  xy/src/com/Test.java:5: package com.thoughtworks.xstream does not exist
  import com.thoughtworks.xstream.*;
  ^
  1 error
```

Comment: Can you edit your question to provide us with the exact error?

Comment: I have added the exact error.

Comment: you can't include external libraries easily in a normal jar. You need special tasks like one-jar to accomplish that.

Answer (score 4):

You should try without the includes attribute:

```
<fileset dir="lib" />
```

And in the jar part you include the classes like this:

```
<zipgroupfileset includes="*.jar" dir="lib"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't put external libraries into a jar and expect the classloader to use those jars. Unfortunately this is not supported.

There are ant tasks like [one jar](http://one-jar.sourceforge.net/index.php?page=build-tools&file=ant) that help you, to create a jar file, that contains everything you need.

This bit is from the [background information of one jar](http://one-jar.sourceforge.net/index.php?page=introduction&file=background):

> Unfortunately this is does not work. The Java Launcher$AppClassLoader
>   does not know how to load classes from a Jar inside a Jar with this
>   kind of Class-Path. Trying to use
>   jar:file:jarname.jar!/commons-logging.jar also leads down a dead-end.
>   This approach will only work if you install (i.e. scatter) the
>   supporting Jar files into the directory where the jarname.jar file is
>   installed.
>
> Another approach is to unpack all dependent Jar files and repack them
>   inside the jarname.jar file. This approach tends to be fragile and
>   slow, and can suffer from duplicate resource issues.

Other Alternative:

- [jarjar](https://code.google.com/p/jarjar/): Jar Jar Links is a utility that makes it easy to repackage Java libraries and embed them into your own distribution

Comment: Not quite accurate, some applications such as Hadoop, for example,  support the convention of putting jars in the lib directory of a jar and the application handles getting them on the classpath.

Comment: @DavidParks but thats because Hadoop uses an own classloaders. So this is application specific and not part of the official jar definiton.

Answer (score 0):

I also use ant to include a number of dependency JARs in my JAR. My compile task looks like this. Perhaps something similar will work for you.

```
<target name="compile" depends="init">
   <javac srcdir="${src}" destdir="${build}" includeantruntime="false">
    <classpath>
      <pathelement path="${classpath}" />
      <fileset dir="${deps}">
         <include name="**/*.jar"/>
      </fileset>
    </classpath>
  </javac>
  <copy todir="${build}">
    <fileset dir="${src}" excludes="**/*.java"/>
  </copy>
</target>
```

Answer (score 0):

sometimes u can use jar contents directly, just unzip

```
        <unzip src="/Developer-Java/mysql-connector-java/mysql-connector-java-5.1.22-bin.jar" dest="${build_dir}" />
```